# Cross Origin window control

Tags: javascript, oauth

I am trying to build a Google Plus login through my web application same as you can see on foursquare.com via a oauth popup. The application shows following error in console.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://airus.com:3000" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var REDIRECT    =   'http://airus.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback';
    function login(url, x) {
        var win         =   window.open(url, "windowname1", 'width=400, height=600'); 
        var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
            console.log(win.document.URL);
            if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                var url =   win.document.URL;
                win.close();
                x.reload();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
    $("#link").click(function(){
        x = location;
        login($(this).attr('href'), x);
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually spot on:

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

So you have to serve your site via https (SSL, port 443). So that the url of your page becomes https://airus.com  (:443)